# ASP Classic: Unmask Credit Card number

Tags: encryption, asp-classic

I have code that mask the encrypted cardnumber like this:

```
dim cardNum = MaskCardNumber(rs("CCNum"))
```

output:
xxxxxxxxxxxx1111

Now, i want this one to unmask which is in encrypted form already. Something like this.

output:
4444qwfgrghghghhgh1111

How would I unmask the value of "cardNum"?

any ideas? thanks!

Comment: If you google "Classic ASP Encryption" you should find a few examples, both on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.  Your code implies that you might be storing unencrypted credit card numbers in your database, which is not a good idea.  Payment gateways such as Worldpay, Paypoint, or even Paypal, are designed so that you don't have to store card details at all, they handle that for you

Comment: @john: actually the cards already encrypted, however it is mask. I just want to unmask it, and passed it to another page in its encrypted form. anyway thanks for the tips!.

Answer (score 0):

I am using query.maskedinput.js Version: 1.4.1 I referred https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/blob/bb66bf9b1c3eddd1d2349cee103127ae08d0a877/demo/index.html

the unmasking is done by $("input").blur(function() { $("#info").html("Unmasked value: " + $(this).mask());

example Masking is

$("#pannumber").mask("aaaaa 9999 a");

Unmasking

$("#pannumber").blur(function() {

var pannumber= $(this).mask() ;